# How to format to two decimal places only if decimals required

Tags: excel, vba

I have columns where data will either be a whole number or a long decimal (e.g. 0.6666667).

I want to format the decimals to two decimal places, but I don't want the whole numbers to show .00 decimals.

I saw a similar question elsewhere with this code as an answer, but this leaves a decimal point after a whole number (**5.** rather than **5**):

```vb
Range("Q8:Q500").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=(Q8-INT(Q8))>0"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
 Selection.NumberFormat = "[=0]0;.##"
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

I tried an if statement to format based on whether there is a decimal point present:

```vb
For Each Cell In Columns("Q")
    If Cell.Value = "*.*" Then
        Cell.NumberFormat = "0.00"
    Else
        Cell.NumberFormat = "General"
    End If
Next
```

I would rather not add columns as the file is massive already.

Comment: Instead of `If Cell.Value = "*.*" Then`, compare with Like operator: `If Cell.Value Like "*.*" Then`

Comment: `IF Round(Cell.Value,2) <> int(cell.value) Then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a sub like this - before applying the numberformat it checks for errors or text - and quits. By that you are sure that only numbers are handled.

```vb
Sub reformatNumber(c As Range)

If IsError(c.value) Then Exit Sub
If Not IsNumeric(c.Value2) Then Exit Sub

If Int(c.Value2) <> c.Value2 Then
    c.NumberFormat = "0.00"
Else
    c.NumberFormat = "0"
End If

End Sub
```

You can test it like this:

```vb
Sub test_reformat()
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Selection
    reformatNumber c
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional formatting.
Example of it working:

[image]

Select range, format it as "0", add conditional formatting with custom formula "=A1<>round(A1,0)", with the number format "0.00"